# Как узнать путь до моих файлов, которые лежат рядом с .pro?

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужно узнать путь до папки src и следовательно файлов, которые в ней лежат. Эта папка лежит рядом с файлом Laboratory1.pro

На данный момент я сделал так

```
#ifndef CONFIGURATION_H
#define CONFIGURATION_H

#include <QString>
#include <QDir>

namespace Configuration
{
    static const QString test1 = "E:/Education/Practics/Projects C++(QT)/Laboratory1/src/test1.txt";
    static const QString test2 = "E:/Education/Practics/Projects C++(QT)/Laboratory1/src/test2.txt";
    static const QString test3 = "E:/Education/Practics/Projects C++(QT)/Laboratory1/src/test3.txt";
}

#endif // CONFIGURATION_H
```

Почему я сделал именно так. Объясняю. Я мог использовать файл ресурсов и моя проблема была бы решена, но есть большое НО. У меня есть метод, который реализует в себе проверку, является ли выбранный файл файлом и возможно ли его открыть. Вот в чём особенность ресурсов, так это в том, что если я однажды открыл файл, то при его удалении, мой метод будет возвращать true, что файл якобы остался, а как вы поняли это абсолютно неверно. Реализация моего конструктора с QTimer и моим методом на проверку существования файла привожу ниже.

```
#include "Checkfile.h"

#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

CheckFile::CheckFile(const QString &fileName, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    fileName(fileName)
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);

    if (this->exists())
        qDebug() << "Size " << fileName << " is" << this->size() << "byte\n";

    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &CheckFile::exists);
    connect(this, &CheckFile::fileDisappeared, [&](){
        disconnect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &CheckFile::exists);
        qDebug() << "File " << fileName << " was disconnected from observation!";
    });

    // Каждую секунду будет обновление данных для сигнала &QTimer::timeout
    timer->start(1000);
}

CheckFile::~CheckFile()
{
    delete timer;
}

bool CheckFile::exists()
{
    // Если это файл, а не каталог и можем открыть
    if (QFileInfo::exists(fileName) && QFileInfo(fileName).isFile())
        return true;

    // Вызов сигнала, что с файлом что-то не так
    emit fileDisappeared();

    return false;
}

qint64 CheckFile::size() const
{
    return QFileInfo(fileName).size();
}
```

Мой main.cpp для понимания, что вообще я делаю с файлом конфигурации

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "Checkfile.h"
#include "Configuration.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QList<CheckFile*> checkFilesList;

    checkFilesList.push_back(new CheckFile(Configuration::test1));
    checkFilesList.push_back(new CheckFile(Configuration::test2));
    checkFilesList.push_back(new CheckFile(Configuration::test3));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Вопрос. Как узнать путь до моего каталога src, который лежит рядом с Laboratory1.pro безкостыльными методами?

Если использовать файл ресурсов, то код в Конфигурации будет выглядеть так.

```
#ifndef CONFIGURATION_H
#define CONFIGURATION_H

#include <QString>
#include <QDir>

namespace Configuration
{
    static const QString test1 = ":/files/src/test1.txt";
    static const QString test2 = ":/files/src/test2.txt";
    static const QString test3 = ":/files/src/test3.txt";
}

#endif // CONFIGURATION_H
```

При удалении файла непосредственно средствами Windows из каталога, функция CheckFile::exists, всё равно будет возвращать true, что абсолютно неверно, а мой костыльный вариант работает как надо когда я удаляю файл, то я об этом узнаю. Но он не будет работать на других машинах по понятным причинам(пути на машинах могут быть другие).

Comment: файл ресурсов для этого нужен...

Comment: Видимо, вы не читали мою проблему, я описал почему не могу использовать файл ресурсов. При подключении ресурса файлов и вызове моего метода CheckFile::exists он всегда будет возвращать true, даже если файл был создан. Мой метод работает так, что если я в процессе работы программы удалю файл из директории, то узнаю об этом! С файлом ресурсов возникает проблема!

Comment: если так, то файл ресурсов тут ВООБЩЕ не нужен, это как ты удаляешь main.cpp в процессе выполнения программы

Comment: Прочитайте мою проблему ещё раз, пальцем в небо тыкаете

Comment: *"при его удалении, мой метод будет возвращать true, что файл якобы остался"* - В приведенном коде никакого удаления не видно. Зачем вы что-то удаляете и почему вы думаете, что если путь задать по-другому, то удаление сработает? *"CheckFile::exists он всегда будет возвращать true, даже если файл был создан"* - что?

Comment: Верно, его в коде и не будет видно. Потому что удаляется файл средставими windows, непосредственно в каталоге. Нажимаем пкм. -> удалить файл. Программа уведомит, что файл удалён. Файл ресурсов работает так, что он хранит в кэше файл, и я его могу прочитать, даже если его удалил из каталога, во время работы программы. Если же путь задать непосредственно(полностью до файла), то при удалении файла программа не сможет его считать.

Comment: Мой код на github, если будет понятнее https://github.com/unitedtimur/laboratory1_QT

Comment: Файлы ресурсов обычно в exe хранится рядом с кодом...

Comment: Да, блин, проблема с этими ресурсами. Объясню алгоритм, почему ресурсы не работают. Может понятнее будет. Прописываю пути до файлов, указываю их при инициализации и добавлении в список. Теперь запускаю программу. Если я удалю файлы средствами windows, то функция CheckFile::exists всё равно будет возвращать true, что мол файл есть и всё ок, я его вижу. Но это же не так. Если делать с прописыванием полного пути до файлов, как я сделал я, без ресурсов, то при удалении файлов средставами windows, программа успешно меня информирует, что файлы были удалены!

Comment: Что вы называете "файлом ресурсов"? `"E:/Education/Practics/Projects C++(QT)/Laboratory1/src/test1.txt"`? Так это же просто файл, нет? *"Если же путь задать непосредственно(полностью до файла), то при удалении файла программа не сможет его считать."* - а вы ожидаете чего-то другого? Вообще непонятно как заголовок вопроса связан с его содержимым.

Comment: Файлом ресурсом я называю непосредственно ресурс с расширением .qrc, созданный в QT. В нём я прописываю пути до файлов в src. Да, это просто файл, и мне нужно узнать, удалился он или нет, в процессе работы программы. Ресурсы этого позволить не могут.

Comment: Тогда отредактируйте вопрос и включите в его именно код с примером, использующим эти ресурусы. чтоб хоть кто-то мог воспроизвести

Comment: Добавил в конце пример

Comment: А зачем контролировать непонятный каталог, в котором расположен файл проекта. Задавайте любой произвольный каталог в параметрах вызова программы. Дело в том, что файл проекта имеет смысл только при разработке приложения. Собранное приложение знать не знает про какие-то pro файлы. Если же Вы настаиваете на Вашей постановке задачи, то сделать нужно следующее: в файле проекта добавляете дефайн, в котором указываете путь к файлу проекта, а в своей программе уже свободно используете этот дефайн. Пока не готов более подробно ответить. Еду в электричке.

Comment: Ну правильно, если запихнуть файлы в ресурсы, то они и будут лежать в ресурсах, а удаление **других** файлов в папке с проектом на них никак не повлияет. Вообще как я понял, вам стоит указывать путь относительно папки с исполняемым файлом (не с проектом) и соответственно копировать свои test1.txt в ту папку при сборке.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что могу прописать дефайном путь к проекту, но это костыльно, ведь на другой машине путь к проекту может быть другим и всё не будет работать. Такую задачу мне поставила бабка в универе)

Comment: Я думал с копированием файла в папку со сборкой, но мне тоже это показалось жёстким костылём

Comment: вы наверное не понимаете, что qrc транслируется в c++ файл, это массив типа char в котором содержаться файлы ресурсов запакованные zip-ом, т.е. это железно вшито в вашу программу

Comment: ну а чтобы файл лежал в одном месте, кладите его в пользовательский каталог C:/Users/...

Comment: путь к проекту можно определить в переменной препроцессора из qt-проекта, например `DEFINES += PRJ_PATH=$$(PWD)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй макрос `__FILE__` . Получишь путь до того файла, где ты прописал этот макрос в виде константной си строки, а дальше можешь просто извлечь подстроку и получить путь до директории.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно сослаться на файл, лежащий в папке с кодом, я делаю что-то такое:

```
QString path = QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/../../src/file.txt";
```

где `src` это папка с кодом.

Первый переход на папку вверх выводит вас из папки `debug` или `release` (в зависимости от сборки) в папку `build-...`, следующий в папку, родительскую для папки с кодом, оттуда переходим в папку с кодом.

Работает при переносе на другой компьютер под windows, на других системах путь к бинарнику относительно папки с кодом может отличаться и надо чуть скорректировать строку.

Comment: Вот именно, что при переносе на другую систему пути будут отличаться. Да и решение подниматься на уровни выше тоже не очень, так как собирать могут вообще на другом диске, вне исходных файлов.

Comment: Дефолтно Qt Creator собирает исполняемый файл в папке build, расположенной на уровень выше папки с кодом. Я пользуюсь этим подходом для хранения данных для юнит-тестов, которые как раз лежат около папки с кодом, но не имеют отношения к самому исполняемому файлу и лежат всегда в одной локации относительно кода.

Answer (score 0):

Решение, которое у меня созрело:

**pro-файл**

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

DEFINES += PRJ_PATH='\\"$${PWD}\\"'

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString str = PRJ_PATH;
    qDebug()<<"PATH:" << str;

    return a.exec();
}
```

И все-таки я настоятельно рекомендую не использовать это решение, поскольку при переносе собранного приложения с компьютера на компьютер оно не будет работать. Предлагаю использовать решение с указанием пути через аргумент. Это решение позволяет переносить приложение с одного компьютера на другой и натравливать его на произвольную директорию, в которой будут лежать обрабатываемые Вами файлы.